# How do I respec a follower in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I didn't like the skill I chosen for the first follower I found. Is it possible to respec his skill later on?

Comment: For the search engines: Other ways to phrase this question are "How can I change my followers'skills" and "can you change follower skills in diablo 3"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of **2.0.1.** (maybe even few patches earlier) there is no more retrain button,you can now **freely choose skills** for your follower.

Meaning,if you don't like the chosen skill,you can simply click on the other one to activate it.
Changing skills has no cooldown and can be done anytime,even in combat.
But it won't reset the actual cooldown on skill to prevent abuse.

Answer (score 50):

**Note: this answer is out of date in version 2.0 and above.**

You have to right click their portrait in the main window, not the follower window (default hotkey <kbd>F</kbd>). There will be an option called "Retrain" which will let you redistribute her skill choices. This is absolutely free and has no cooldowns or anything like that, by the way.

[image: Retrain]