# Can followers' spell be respeced?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I respec a follower in Diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66341/how-do-i-respec-a-follower-in-diablo-3)

http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Followers

In diablo iii. Scoundrels for example. I chose slow. Say I want poison latter. Can I change that? How?

Comment: Right click the portrait and choose retrain

Comment: If it's going to be so easy why don't they make it easy all the way but not hiding the feature?