# What skills to give the enchantress

Tags: diablo-iii

I have my enchantress up to level 25, and I don't know which skill to give her?  Any thoughts?

Also is there a skill reset later in the game?

Comment: You can right click on her picture and press retrain at any time, so just try out all the skills and see which ones you like with no consequences!

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66341/how-do-i-respec-a-follower-in-diablo-3

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the strengths and weaknesses of each follower?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67598/what-are-the-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-each-follower)

Comment: This duplicates neither of those, though his incidental inquiry of whether a respect is possible is duplicated, sure, the strenghs/weaknesses post *does not* discuss specific ideal skill selections.

Comment: @Less The ideal skill selections are going to vary based on what you want to get out of them.  The other question gives you ideas of both who to take and what skills to take if you are looking for various things.  I don't know how we're going to do any better than that.  Otherwise this is way too open-ended.

Comment: @bwarner I fail to see how a question asking for help with a choice with a maximum of fifteen possible outcomes is too open ended. Honestly, even a skill by skill breakdown is well within the scope of a reasonable question.

Comment: I did not see the duplicate because I looked for the word Enchantress, nor did it come up in the suggested list.  ... Thank you Mr Smooth I did not about retrain.  I thought it was perm so that is why I asked before "trying"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All followers can Retrain their skills at any time for free.

The skills I use on mine are Charm, Powered Armor, Erosion and Mass Control. I chose Mass Control to have fun seeing big monsters turn into chickens, as this was a non-WD character - however as a recommendation, I'd actually suggest Focused Mind at that level.

**Charm** can be very useful in situations where the lead monster of a pack suddenly stops and turns around to beat its buddies, in a narrow corridor - thus buying extra time to spam AoE distance attacks.
Its alternative, *Forceful Push* is something I have not tried yet, could be useful ***if*** the followers really do full weapon damage on using their specials (normally they do a pitiful fraction like 12.5%)

**Powered Armor** helps with all attacks not just non-projectile; and also a lot of 'projectile' attacks can't be reflected, I believe this is the generally superior choice for this slot over *Reflect Missiles*, unless you want to micro and switch them based on area.

**Erosion** will greatly help with dps in some situations and is useful for single enemies as well as for groups, and has a shorter CD than *Disorient*.

**Focused Mind** is an AoE aura adding 3% IAS. Blizzard even had to nerf IAS so you know its a good stat ;). The alternative of *Mass Control* is not as helpful, I consider it more of a novelty factor.

Comment: Mass Control has saved my life on many an occasion. If you're in a group setting, Focused Mind may be more useful for raw DPS, but if you're interested in staying alive, Mass Control can be a lifesaver. The same goes for Disorient.